Generate a string type from two objects keys separated by a dot
I have two constants, something like
const colors = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: '',
};

const variations = {
  100: '',
  200: '',
  300: '',
}

And I want to create a type from these two objects keys that accepts a.100, a.200, a.300, b.100, b.200, b.300, c.100 and so on, something like
const colorVariations: ThisTypeNameHere = 'a.100'; // good
const colorVariations: ThisTypeNameHere = 'b.200'; // good
const colorVariations: ThisTypeNameHere = 'c.100'; // good
const colorVariations: ThisTypeNameHere = 'a200';  // bad
const colorVariations: ThisTypeNameHere = 'a.950'; // bad


Can be done using template literal types!
const colors = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: '',
};

const variations = {
  100: '',
  200: '',
  300: '',
};

// Extracting keys from colors and variations
type ColorKeys = keyof typeof colors;
type VariationKeys = keyof typeof variations;

// Creating the combination type
type ColorVariations = `${ColorKeys}.${VariationKeys}`;

const colorVariations: ColorVariations = 'a.100'; // good
const colorVariations1: ColorVariations = 'b.200'; // good
const colorVariations2: ColorVariations = 'c.100'; // good
const colorVariations3: ColorVariations = 'a200';  // bad (TypeScript will throw an error)
const colorVariations4: ColorVariations = 'a.950'; // bad (TypeScript will throw an error)


Is that easy? Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for, didn't know much about template literal types.

@RafaelBerro No problem man! More than happy to help!

You are looking for template literal types:
const colors = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: '',
};

const variations = {
  100: '',
  200: '',
  300: '',
}

type ThisTypeNameHere = `${keyof typeof colors}.${keyof typeof variations}`

You want to get all possible type of keys of variations and colors and then create a combination of them.
Playground
